# Why is a compound index created for one field?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with users in MongoDB and I want to create indexes for the email field, I do this in MongoDB Compass by specifying the "Build index in background" parameter, but when I do this, a compound index is created:
[image]
Sample document:

```json
{
  "_id":{
    "$oid":"6060d34aaf85dd1071ca6406"
  },
  "email":"example@mail.com",
  "password":"somehash",
  "role":"admin",
  "state":true,
  "createdAt":{
    "date":{
      "$date":"2021-02-08T19:13:59.399Z"
    },
    "timestamp":1612811639.399607
  },
  "extraData":{
    "jwt":"somejwt",
    "language":"en"
  }
}
```

There is only one email field, why is the compound being created?
And do I understand correctly that if I have a lot of read-write operations in the database, I need to build all the indexes in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `text` index types are compound indexes even if you specify just one key.

If you apply a normal index for the same key, it would show up as a regular index.

If you want all your read/write operations to be unaffected while building the index, you have to use the `background: true` option. But, this will consume more time.

Comment: Okay, what if I need to create text indexes for multiple fields in a document? Do I need to merge them into one index?

Comment: There can be only one text index on a collection